# CMake/CTest - Where was defined test XYZ?

Tags: cmake, ctest

After building a CMake/CTest setup with many tests I see a growing problem.
If `ctest -R test_some_side_corner_item_XYZ` fails, how can I systematically track back to the place where somebody added the test `test_some_side_corner_item_XYZ`?

I understand that there is the problem that we can add macros on top of `add_test()` which makes it a bit harder to make any clear answer - but still.

It appears [`cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) does not have any obvious ways to achieve this - and the same seems for [`ctest`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html).

Comment: `track back` you mean like track back in time? So can't you just `grep -r test_some_side_corner_item_XYZ` your project? `that we can add macros on top of add_test()` - so add a macro on top of add_test that logs all of it's uses. And then you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ctest` command line [options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#options) to find the *exact* line in your CMakeLists.txt hierarchy where the `add_test()` call was made. We can use the `--show-only=json-v1` option to display JSON-formatted meta-data about a test:

```
ctest -R test_some_side_corner_item_XYZ --show-only=json-v1
```

An example of what this prints would be:

```
{
  "backtraceGraph" :
  {
    "commands" :
    [
      "add_test"
    ],
    "files" :
    [
      "C:/workspace/myproject/CMakeLists.txt"
    ],
    "nodes" :
    [
      {
        "file" : 0
      },
      {
        "command" : 0,
        "file" : 0,
        "line" : 34,
        "parent" : 0
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

This lists the `CMakeLists.txt` file where `add_test()` was called for this test, and the line number (`"line" : 34`) where it was called.

---

From the CMake documentation, the `--show-only` option will not actually run the test, but will only display its information:

> `-N,--show-only[=<format>]`
>
> Disable actual execution of tests.
>
> This option tells CTest to list the tests that would be run but not actually run them. Useful in conjunction with the `-R` and `-E` options.

Note, the `-R` option is a regex to match the test(s) you want, so to get an **exact** match, you can anchor the test name with `^` and `$`:

```
ctest -R ^test_some_side_corner_item_XYZ$ --show-only=json-v1
```

Comment: WAUV! @squareskittles